# Postgres в Docker (docker-compose): как разместить данные на хосте?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
postgres:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
  ports:
    - "5433:5432"
  volumes:
    - ~/tmp/lib:/var/lib/postgresql/10/main
    - ~/tmp/log:/var/log/postgresql
    - ~/tmp/etc:/etc/postgresql
web:
  image: my/build
  ports:
    - "4000:4000"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
```

Но когда запускаю приложение, и даже если вручную создаю базу, то никаких данных в tmp/lib нет. и логов тоже, вообще ничего. Как сделать чтобы postgres размещал свои данные в папке на хосте?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ тут (нужно было указать подкаталог):

> The default is /var/lib/postgresql/data, but if the data volume you're using is a fs mountpoint (like with GCE persistent disks), Postgres initdb recommends a subdirectory (for example /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ) be created to contain the data.

Answer (score 1):

В контейнере отсутствует директория /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
а есть /var/lib/postgresql/data
это легко проверить набрав в косоли хост-машины
  docker exec -it $(docker ps -lq) bash
и далее : cd /var/lib/postgresql/data,
Но это не решает вашего вопроса.